# Count view not working on navbar after chancing page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have a page with a navbar where the count of posts work very well, but after I go to a other page, lets say to contacts the counts display as `()`. How can I fix this problem?

```
on index.html the result is : total posts (43434)
on contacts.html the result is : total posts ()
```

index.html

```html
<div> total posts ({{ postcounts }}) </div>
```

views.py

```py
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(active=True)
    pcounts = posts.count()
    context = {
        'postcounts':pcounts,
        }
    
    return render(request, 'posts/index.html', context)
```

Comment: you only passing  `postcounts` to `index.html`, for it to show on `contacts.html` you need to also pass postcounts in the view that use it too

Comment: do you mean I must write a view for every other page to display the count? This means that I must write for example 20 same views if I have 20 other pages. Isn't there a easier way?

Comment: this is pretty simple, create a `base.html` and passing  `postcounts` to it, the other pages just expand `base.html`. You can read this to understand how it work https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/

Comment: no, didn't worked, the same problem on base.html too. I will try to play with the views.